# Error: for frame [base_laser_link]: Fixed Frame[] does not exist

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I was fellowing the tutorial in http://wiki.ros.org/laser_pipeline/Tutorials/IntroductionToWorkingWithLaserScannerData, I got some problem with Visualizing Your Laser Scan. I played back the bag Mapping1.bag, laser is publishing on /base_scan. When I run rviz, I do not know what to fill in fixed frame. I tried a lot of frame, but still got the error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286464/error:-for-frame-%5Bbase_laser_link%5D:-fixed-frame%5B%5D-does-not-exist/) by [Jeffery](https://answers.ros.org/users/34274/jeffery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved. Just change the fixed frame to base_laser_link.

---

Originally posted by [Jeffery](https://answers.ros.org/users/34274/jeffery/) with karma: 46 on 2018-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1